# how to access the value of a UISwitch

Tags: ios, uiswitch

i have created a settingsView and also a view that gives you a choice to be notified if you want at a certain time its a yes or no but i do not know how to access the value of the uiswitch i know instead of trying to get the views object i should try the preference that the state has been saved to but i don't know how i just want to tap my `UISwitch` and then in the settingsView the `UILabel` gets filled but i don't know how to access the value on the `UISwitch` once tapped i have saved it in `NSUserDefaults` in the notifiedView but do not know how to access that value in the settingsView so i can put in the settingsView

```
if (UISwitch.on)
{
   //notify me please
} else {
   // leave as is 
}
```

of course that's just a quick layout of how i want it to be though and also where do i put the it in the settingsView viewDidLoad, `viewWillAppear` or both please help im a new be as well so please be kind if i have said things that you would deem not the right syntax thanks

Comment: Is your question how to retrieve information from User Defaults or from the Switch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
// add this code in your switch touch event

- (IBAction)YourSwitch:(UISwitch*)sender
{
    if (UISwitch.on)
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setBool:true forKey:@"Sound"];
        [defaults synchronize];

    }
    else
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setBool:false forKey:@"Sound"];
        [defaults synchronize];

    }
}
```

Add this code in your viewdidload .

```
BOOL swithState = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Sound"];

if (swithState)
{
    _ref_slider.on=true;
}
else
{
    _ref_slider.on=false;
}
```

i hope this code is useful for you.

Comment: yell yeah you are the man but instead of me putting the NSString *str in viewDidLoad i put it in viewWillAppear and that worked perfectly thanks heaps

Comment: i also have this in my IBAction method

Comment: BOOL isOn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"actor0"];
    isOn = !isOn;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] setBool:isOn forKey:@"actor0"];
    self.actorSwitch.on = isOn;

Comment: NSDictionary *defaults = @{"ok0": YES, "ok1": YES, "ok2": YES,
                               "ok3": YES, "ok4": YES, "ok5": YES};
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaults];

Answer (score 0):

Just make a UISwitch property in your UIViewController and make sure you set it in the init/viewDidLoad of your class (from an IBOutlet or when you programmatically add it to your view). Then you can access the on-property of the UISwitch from anywhere within your class (and a load of extra features!) and use the if-statement as you want..

Apple Doc ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

If your are using storyboard then hook up your UISwitch's action and write the below code in it.

```
- (IBAction)switchTapped:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isOn]) {
           // your code
    }
    else
    {
         // your code
    }

}
```